# When trying to save an excel spreadsheet in python I get this error: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have been trying to take a sheet from an xls spreadsheet and add it to a sheet within another spreadsheet that contains multiple sheets without it overwriting the whole file and deleting the other sheets within it.

For this I have imported the first sheet as a pandas dataframe and then ran it through the function, however it always shows the error: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'

Here is the code that I have been using for this:

```
import pandas as pd

def append_df_to_excel(filename, df, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=None,
                   truncate_sheet=False, 
                   **to_excel_kwargs):
    """
    Append a DataFrame [df] to existing Excel file [filename]
    into [sheet_name] Sheet.
    If [filename] doesn't exist, then this function will create it.

    Parameters:
      filename : File path or existing ExcelWriter
                 (Example: '/path/to/file.xlsx')
      df : dataframe to save to workbook
      sheet_name : Name of sheet which will contain DataFrame.
                   (default: 'Sheet1')
      startrow : upper left cell row to dump data frame.
                 Per default (startrow=None) calculate the last row
                 in the existing DF and write to the next row...
      truncate_sheet : truncate (remove and recreate) [sheet_name]
                       before writing DataFrame to Excel file
      to_excel_kwargs : arguments which will be passed to `DataFrame.to_excel()`
                        [can be dictionary]

    Returns: None
    """
    from openpyxl import load_workbook

    # ignore [engine] parameter if it was passed
    if 'engine' in to_excel_kwargs:
        to_excel_kwargs.pop('engine')

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')

    # Python 2.x: define [FileNotFoundError] exception if it doesn't exist 
    try:
        FileNotFoundError
    except NameError:
        FileNotFoundError = IOError


    try:
        # try to open an existing workbook
        writer.book = load_workbook(filename)

        # get the last row in the existing Excel sheet
        # if it was not specified explicitly
        if startrow is None and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
            startrow = writer.book[sheet_name].max_row

        # truncate sheet
        if truncate_sheet and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
            # index of [sheet_name] sheet
            idx = writer.book.sheetnames.index(sheet_name)
            # remove [sheet_name]
            writer.book.remove(writer.book.worksheets[idx])
            # create an empty sheet [sheet_name] using old index
            writer.book.create_sheet(sheet_name, idx)

        # copy existing sheets
        writer.sheets = {ws.title:ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}
    except FileNotFoundError:
        # file does not exist yet, we will create it
        pass

    if startrow is None:
        startrow = 0

    # write out the new sheet
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs)

    # save the workbook
    writer.save()



dataFrame = pd.read_excel(r'C:\John\spreadsheets\royalty_test\Rawfiles\Blackwells_royalty_Other_2018_04.xls')


append_df_to_excel(r'C:\John\spreadsheets\royalty_test\Blackwells_NON-OS_Royalty_2018_04.xlsx',dataFrame,sheet_name='Orders',index=False)
```

The traceback is as follows:

```
runfile('C:/John/python/practicepython/sdafdf.py', wdir='C:/John/python  /practicepython')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-255-58955ae481da>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/John/python/practicepython/sdafdf.py', wdir='C:/John/python/practicepython')

  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/John/python/practicepython/sdafdf.py", line 86, in <module>
append_df_to_excel(r'C:\John\spreadsheets\royalty_test\Blackwells_NON-OS_Royalty_2018_04.xlsx',dataFrame,sheet_name='Orders',index=False)

  File "C:/John/python/practicepython/sdafdf.py", line 50, in append_df_to_excel
writer.book = load_workbook(filename)

  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 224, in load_workbook
pivot_caches = parser.pivot_caches

  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\packaging\workbook.py", line 126, in pivot_caches
records = get_rel(self.archive, cache.deps, cache.id, RecordList)

  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\packaging\relationship.py", line 153, in get_rel
rel = next(deps.find(cls.rel_type))
```

Comment: Can you also add the complete traceback of the error? That way it is often easier to identify the cause of the error.

Comment: I have added the traceback that I get in the console from this, is this what you meant?

Comment: yes, indeed! from it, you can see that the error occurs in line 50 of your code `writer.book = load_workbook(filename)`. However when I try to reproduce the issue, the code seems to work as expected. Have you tried it with a different excel file?